# Why columns in views are always nullable?

Tags: postgresql

I'm using postgreSQL. Why the fields in the views always are nullable? I get that in some situation computed columns can be NULL, but in the below snippet I only "forward" those data.

I noticed that MySQL behaves like I'd have, and I don't need special feature from psql, so I think I'll switch to MySQL.

But I really wonder WHY postgreSQL doesn't behave "normally"?

It is quite annoying when you are working with system like SQLx in Rust bridging SQL and Rust types since you cannot rely on this tool when you refers to views in your Rust code.

```
postgres=# CREATE TABLE a( field INT NOT NULL);
CREATE TABLE
postgres=# CREATE VIEW b AS SELECT field FROM a;
CREATE VIEW

postgres=# SELECT column_name,is_nullable, data_type           
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name ='a';
 column_name | is_nullable | data_type 
-------------+-------------+-----------
 field       | NO          | integer
(1 row)

postgres=# SELECT column_name,is_nullable, data_type
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name ='b';
 column_name | is_nullable | data_type 
-------------+-------------+-----------
 field       | YES         | integer
(1 row)
```

Comment: "normal"  is usually, what the standards say and what the developers do from it, you have tolive with it

Comment: @nbk I can "live with it", but I'd like to understand this counter intuitive fact, don't you think? Because there is no reason we cannot derive the "NOT NULL" property in the view

Comment: If the column (non-)nullability was inherited from the table structure, then when you change the column property in the table, you would have to change (or even delete and recreate) the view.

Comment: a why can only answer a developer, that is an internal decision

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of the view, nullability is just informational. No constraint is enforced on the view itself, but on the underlying tables.

I can see two uses of nullability information:

- It tells the optimizer something.  That is not interesting in the case of a view, because the statement is rewritten to operate on the underlying tables anyway, and there we have that information.
- It is nice information for the user.

So we are missing out on the second point here. But if you know the view definition, you can figure this out for yourself, albeit with a little extra work.

So I would say that PostgreSQL doesn't have it because it is not very important, and because nobody cared to implement it.

Comment: I know this is not in the SE way to say "thank you" in the comments, but THANK YOU @Laurenz Albe for this very explaining and emphatic answer!

Comment: That's perfectly fine, and you are welcome.

Comment: I've edited my question about the "But if you know the view definition, you can figure this out for yourself": with SQLx, I don't only need to infer this myself, SQLx wants an actual proof of it :)

Comment: For what does this SQLx use that information?

Comment: To know whether the field will be `i64` or `Option<i64>`.

Comment: Ok, and what is the problem with always having the latter?

Comment: Well...It forces me to add some really useless `.unwrap()` in my Rust code. As a consequence, I will no longer be able to know if a field could possibly be `NULL` or not.  (without having all my DB in head, which is not the goal of using this kind of lib).

Comment: Well, looks like you'll have to add those `unwrap`s.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this is *just the way it is* in PostgreSQL (which I understand is a sucky answer). It seems like under certain conditions for certain versions of PostgreSQL, a view's column may be attributed as **non-nullable**. This [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17306969/5059085) gives the example where if the field is a primary key of the base table, in a vanilla view, it is showing as **non-nullable** in the view's schema.
I suppose PostgreSQL has some strict requirements on what it assumes can truly be **non-nullable** in a view definition.